# How to print data in an Axios call to flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios

Hi there I am doing a project with a React Frontend and Flask Backend. I am using axios to make calls from the Frontend to the Backend, but I am having trouble accessing the data I am sending with my request. I have tried several different methods of accessing the data but have no luck printing my variables.

Here is my flask endpoint:

```
@app.route('/login')
@cross_origin()
def login():
    print(request.data)
    return "Hello World"
```

Here is my axios call:

```
let options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: flaskEndpoint+ "/login",
            data: JSON.stringify(loginData),
            // crossOrigin:'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
            crossOrigin:'*',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            json: true
        }

        console.log(JSON.stringify(loginData))

        axios(options)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                // this.setState({
                //     
                // })

                setAuth(true);
                Cookies.set("user", "loginTrue");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log("Error in the axios call:" + error);
            })

    }
```

And here is the result in the flask terminal:
[image]

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way?

Comment: Axios accepts object, not string, in data property. Do :`data: loginData`.

Comment: No luck! Still getting back: b''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I should have used "print(request.json)" instead. Then I could access the data being sent, or use "request.json.get('username')" to get a particular value.